# When is it safe to release an IMFSample and its data?

Tags: c++, com, ms-media-foundation

According to this [Microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx), it looks like we are supposed to release the just-written IMFSample and its buffer right after writing the sample:

```
// Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pSample);
}

SafeRelease(&pSample);
SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
```

But sometimes I get heap corruption errors when doing this.. and if I omit the calls to SafeRelease the sample and buffer, I leak memory, but I don't get heap corruption errors.  From what I understand, the IMFSinkWriter queues up the samples sent to it (with the `WriteSample` function) and writes them in its own good time.. so, it does make sense that heap corruption happens when I release the sample before the sink writer gets a chance to write it.  Is this what is happening?  If so, how should I clean up the memory responsibly?  Do I need to put an asynchronous call back on the sink writer and use that to monitor when samples are finished so I can free the memory?  That seems cumbersome, and I've never seen that done in any Microsoft examples, so I'm sort of wondering what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early release of media sample here is okay, if sink needs to extend the life time of the object, esp. for asynchronous operation, it can and should do additional `AddRef`/`Release` to make sure the interface pointer is valid.

Heap corruptions are often difficult to troubleshoot because incorrect memory access might takes place late, not immediately following incorrect code. If leaking media samples helps with heap corruption, perhaps you should be looking at earlier operations with data: how you obtain media sample interface etc.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I'm investigating the data operations that I perform prior to releasing the media samples.. I think you pointed me in the right direction.  And thanks for clarifying how the sink writer handles the media samples.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up and mention that you were definitely right.  I was overstepping some array bounds!  Thanks again for keeping me from wandering astray with the whole asynchronous memory releasing business.